# git pretty format command does not output proper json file

Tags: python, json, windows, git, dictionary

I am executing the git log pretty format command to genrate a json file from within my script in python. Right now even though the json file is getting generated with proper data it is actually not in the correct JSON format which is not good since I am not able to parse the file. The problem is that the json file that is getting generated is not in the proper string dictionary format. Proper way is when the keys and values are within the double quotes. For e.g:

```
{"commit":"b01c255f69f", "merge":"4037e2cc48a 2237c472953", "author":"joe.simmons@eddu.com", "title":"Merge branch into main", "body":"Branch: sync/iap/4c60eb3_infra_409f2907_to_ad"
},
```

But my output is:

```
{commit:b01c255f69f, merge:4037e2cc48a 2237c472953, author:joe.simmons@eddu.com, title:Merge branch into main, body:Branch: sync/iap/4c60eb3_infra_409f2907_to_ad
},
```

As a result I am having trouble parsing it.

The command that I used within my script to get this json output is:

```
    customer_path = 'git log ' + branch_name + ' ' + '--since="' + log_length + ' days ago"' + ' ' + '--pretty="format:{"commit":"%h", "merge":"%p", "author":"%an", "title":"%s", "body":"%b"}",>' + '"' + json_directory + '"'
    exit_code = os.system(customer_path)
    if exit_code != 0:
        sys.exit(1)
```

Note: branch name is just the branch I want the log off and log_length is the days since so suppose 30 days ago. The main problem is with the pretty format command which is although enclosed within double quotes is not providing the json dictionary within the double quotes. The command is getting executed within the windows cmd shell.

Comment: Just so you know, this will fail if any of those fields contains a double quote or a non-UTF-8 character.  Git isn't designed to produce JSON output.  You'd be better off processing the output in your program via a pipe and handling these cases gracefully.

Comment: @bk2204 I am not sure what you mean when you say the command will fail with double quotes. The command already has double quotes and it is executing and a json file is getting created at the correct path. Only problem is that the " " marks around keys and values are missing.

Comment: Even if you fix the invocation of `git log` so that it works properly in this case, if any one of the fields you're extracting (e.g., the title) contains a double quote or is not encoded in UTF-8, you will end up with invalid JSON.  For example, you'll have a problem with the title, `Fix "broken" code`.  There's no way to avoid this because Git isn't designed to produce JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're generating is not a JSON:

- it *looks like* a JSON with illegal keys and values;
- it cannot handle proper escaping (it even does not care quote characters);
- it's more like JSON-LD whilst delimited by weird always-trailing `',\n'` (assuming you wanted it to be a single array, right?).

So why not using a proper tool to generate JSON and let Git produce simple delimited data so that it could be easily parsed and then transformed to whatever you want *properly*?

One of possible solutions to do that in Python 3 is might be like this (assuming the `git` command generates TSV output but possibly requires some tweaking):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import jsonstreams
import subprocess

branch_name = 'master'
days = '30'
json_output = './log.json'

with subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/git', 'log', f'--since="{days} days ago"', '--pretty=format:%h\t%p\t%an\t%s\t%b', branch_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as input:
    with jsonstreams.Stream(jsonstreams.Type.array, filename=json_output) as output:
        while True:
            line = input.stdout.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            record = line.decode("utf-8").split("\t")
            with output.subobject() as output_e:
                output_e.write('commit', record[0])
                output_e.write('merge', record[1])
                output_e.write('author', record[2])
                output_e.write('title', record[3])
                output_e.write('body', record[4])
```

The script above generates a legal JSON document out of the git output similar to this:

```json
[
    {"commit": "3011203d", "merge": "e84d9feb", "author": "me", "title": "test commit", "body": ""},
    ...
]
```

(Not pretty-printed in the script, but only for the answer snippet.)

Answer (score 1):

As seen [in this example](https://gist.github.com/textarcana/1306223) or [this one](https://gist.github.com/varemenos/e95c2e098e657c7688fd), you would need to add simple quotes in your `format:` in order to make sure the double-quotes `"xx"` are not interpreted by the shell which will run the `git log` command.

```
'--pretty="format:\'{"commit":"%h", ....}%n},\''
                  ^^                         ^^
```

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. Basically printed same output

Comment: @Ashish101 Just for testing, can you then try and escape the double quotes in your format: `\"commit\"`, just to see if those are preserved that way in the `git log` output?

Comment: If I use \' .............\' as suggested by you through your answer I only get a single quote around each dictionary. If I try \"commit\" around keys and values I get the same output as before(indicated in my question) with no quotation whatsoever. But the script executes.

Comment: @Ashish101 I meant "escape the double quote": `\"`, that is double quotes `"`, not single quotes `\'`

Comment: Yes I also tried \" and I did not get the right result as the output was same as I showed in my question